# Почему меняется значение поля структуры?

Tags: c, строки, память, структуры

В программе мы записываем в поле структуры number.str значение поля number.num, которое равно 1025. Но у символьного массива number.str размерность задана так, что это значение не влезет в массив, для корректного выполнения программы размерность символьного массива number.str должны быть равна 5. Но при выполнении программы значение поля number.num почему то меняется на 1024.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    typedef struct
    {
        char str[3];
        int num;
    } NumberRepr;
    
    void format (NumberRepr* number)
    {
        sprintf(number->str, "%3d", number->num);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        NumberRepr number = { .num = 1025 };
    
        format(&number);
    
        printf("str: %s\n", number.str);
        printf("num: %d\n", number.num);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то по большому счету выход за пределы массива - уже UB и пояснять, как именно и что именно происходит - дело дурное.

Тем не менее, вероятно, происходит следующее: выравнивание на 4 байта приводит к такому размещению в памяти: 3 байта `str`, 1 байт заполнителя для выравнивания, 4 байта `num`.

```
##  ##  ##  $$  nn  nn  nn  nn
```

Будем считать, что изначально все байты нулевые:

```
00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
```

Записываем в `num`  1025 (в 16-ричной системе):

```
00  00  00  00  01  04  00  00
```

Записываем 5 байт `1025` с нулевым в конце:

```
31  30  32  35  00  04  00  00
```

Итак, младший байт `num` благополучно занулен, и в `num` теперь 1024.

Вопросы есть?